# How to display BI Publisher multi-select parameter items in a bi publisher report

Tags: bi-publisher

I have a requirement to display the items chosen in a multi select parameter in a bi publisher report. My Data Model's sample data does include the chosen parameter values but I only see the first item selected after placing the parameter in the bi pub report layout and then viewing the report (this includes when I place the parameter in a list object). How do I display in my report all of the items that were selected in my multi-select parameter?

Comment: Please provide the sample XML. You'll probably use `<?for-each:?>` to loop multiple nodes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have been asked to not include the sample XML due to the sensitive nature of our data. As noted I am new to BI Publisher; please provide an example of how we could use  <?for-each:?> to display all items of a multi-select parameter.

Comment: You could always sanitize your example XML showing the basic element relationships and key attributes - this would make it easier using your example. I'll put an answer below with a generic `<?for-each:?>` example if that would be helpful (too much to put into a comment). Providing the input and desired output is necessary to get a useful answer.

Comment: Agree with @DaveCoast, please provide more details. What are the parameters of the concurrent request (and how would they look when the user enters them?), what does your XML look like (at the very least the parameter section), what do you want the output to look like?